# Submit a post request with json data and rest service will generate excel file and return via stream

Tags: javascript, html

Just for a starter I have read most of the question/answers on form submission with download and how to use html + form for file download, but I am still not clear on how to do it because of some specific requirements.

**First** 
I need to send a json data to a rest service via POST along with file name of the excel to be generated on the fly by the service.  When the rest service receive the request, it will generate in memory an excel file based on the requested json data and return it to the client browsers via io stream. The service will not be creating a physical excel file in the server but will immediately return it to the client browsers. 
**Second**
We need just plain HTML & javascript code and no jquery stuff.

My **first** question:
is it possible to this without creating a physical excel file and just sending the excel binary data to the client browsers;

**Second**:
how can I determine when the server finish sending the file to the browser?

**Third**:
How to open a file dialog to save the excel file physical on the client machine?

**Fourth**:
how to configure the server response HTTP headers appropriately?

Comment: "Second, we need just plain HTML & javascript code and no jquery stuff." You expect someone here to write this for you? Not likely. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `content-disposition` header correctly, you'll turn the resulting stream into a file download. Google will have to be your friend on this one since you seem to be asking someone else to execute a contract for you...